# Change Cron to Readable Date and Time

Tags: javascript, angular, cron

How can I change the cron job to readable date and time.

I am using angular6 for the project.

I get the cron job as : `cron : 20 02 * * tue,fri` in the template.

Is there a way to change in the frontend.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I used this [library](https://github.com/harrisiirak/cron-parser). Its pretty simple. Other options is to manually handle converting.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer** : it's not that simple / it depends. Some libraries might help you.

**Long answer** : a cron expression does not represent a date but rather a sequence of date / times from which your job will be run. Additionnaly a cron expression implementation may vary (for instance, some support timezones, some have 5 fields while others have 6, ...)

Therefore, you can have two way to represent your cron expression. Either you parse each field and create a nice string representation such as :

```
0 8 * * MON
```

would give "Every Monday at 8:00".

Your second option is to display when it will run next.

As suggested by @mladen-savić you should use a library that does the job.